# Is there a better way to split a pandas dataframe column based on some characters?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

How do I separate the dates in the Date column below. The separating characters  are either Y,X or " "?

```
xx = {'Code': ["001", "002","003"], 'Date': ["202103151716Y202103151716","202103151716X202103151716","202103151716 202103151716"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=xx)
df
    Code     Date
0   001 202103151716Y202103151716
1   002 202103151716X202103151716
2   003 202103151716 202103151716
```

My solution below finds one of the characters  i.e. Y or  X at a time but  not  both of  them at the same time. It replaces them with " ", then separates them. Is there any way I can write  one  statement that looks for  either X, Y or space (" ") and separates them using  the space?  More like  an OR statement in my solution below as compared to running the three  statements below to replace  Y, then replace X.

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('Y',' ') #Replace Y with space
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('X',' ')
df[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df['Date'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True) # Splits the column into two other columns, Date1 and  Date2
```

Expected Output:

```
    Code    Date                     Date1           Date2
0   001 202103151716 202103151716   202103151716    202103151716
1   002 202103151716 202103151716   202103151716    202103151716
2   003 202103151716 202103151716   202103151716    202103151716
```

Comment: `df[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df['Date'].str.split(r'\D+', 1, expand=True)`?

Comment: Or perhaps more specifically `df[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df['Date'].str.split('[XY ]', 1, expand=True)`

Comment: You are  a legend. That works. Do you mind @WiktorStribiżew explaining this part r'\D+'?

Comment: @Nick this  works  in this instance.

Comment: @Hummer yes, that was the point, that regex (`[XY ]`) is specific to the question you asked. Wiktors regex is more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the column data directly with a `\D+` pattern that matches one or more chars other than digits (since space, `X` or `Y` are non-digits):

```py
import pandas as pd
xx = {'Code': ["001", "002","003"], 'Date': ["202103151716Y202103151716","202103151716X202103151716","202103151716 202103151716"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=xx)
df[['Date1', 'Date2']] = df['Date'].str.split(r'\D+', 1, expand=True)
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date1'])
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date2'])
df
# =>  Code                       Date               Date1               Date2
#   0  001  202103151716Y202103151716 2021-03-15 17:16:00 2021-03-15 17:16:00
#   1  002  202103151716X202103151716 2021-03-15 17:16:00 2021-03-15 17:16:00
#   2  003  202103151716 202103151716 2021-03-15 17:16:00 2021-03-15 17:16:00
```

So, there is no need replacing anything in the first place.

After separating with non-numerical chars, you may use `pd.to_datetime()` to cast the datetime numerical value to a datetime type.

**Note** that `[ XY]` is a character class that matches only a space, `X` or `Y`, but it seems the `\D+` non-digit pattern should be safe with the data you showed.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor  for following up with the answer. Yes, that works  very well.

Comment: Cheeky one-liner `df['Date1'], df['Date2'] = map(pd.to_datetime, zip(*df.Date.str.split('\D+')))` Augments existing dataframe

Comment: Another one-liner `df.assign(**df.Date.str.extract('(?P<Date1>\d+)\D+(?P<Date2>\d+)').apply(pd.to_datetime))`  Produces copy of dataframe

Comment: @piRSquared cheeky but  clever solutions. All tested and, yes they work. Are you able to elaborate  on the usage of  this ?P<Date1>\d+)\D+(?P<Date2>\d+)?

Comment: @Hummer they are variations on WS's solution.  Unless they make perfect sense to you, it is wiser to use the solution in the answer as it is the most obvious as to what is going on.

Comment: @Hummer The `(?P<Date1>...)` is a named capturing group that is used in Pandas to extract a part of a match and automatically use the name of the group to place that submatch into a specific column.